# ClassCastException in Broadcast receiver for ContextImpl

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-context

I have a broadcast receiver that starts a service when a gcm message is received. But I get an exception saying :

Logs:

```
trace->java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver         com.xyz.ab.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException:   com.xyz.ab.gcm.ServiceWrapperContext cannot be cast to  android.app.ContextImpl

 03-19 13:09:11.558: E/(8913): MainApplication: onCreate: uncaughtException:            
thread->mainException was: Unable to start receiver 
com.xyz.ab.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException:   
com.xyz.ab.ServiceWrapperContext cannot be cast to android.app.ContextImpl 
stack trace->java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver 
com.xyz.ab.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.xyz.ab.ServiceWrapperContext cannot be cast to android.app.ContextImpl
03-19 13:09:11.558: E/(8913):  at    
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2520)
03-19 13:09:11.558: E/(8913):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:156)
03-19 13:09:11.558: E/(8913):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1416)
03-19 13:09:11.558: E/(8913):  at   
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
03-19 13:09:11.558: E/(8913):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
03-19 13:09:11.558: E/(8913):  at   
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
03-19 13:09:11.558: E/(8913):  at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 13:09:11.558: E/(8913):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-19 13:09:11.558: E/(8913):  at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
03-19 13:09:11.558: E/(8913):  at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-19 13:09:11.558: E/(8913):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 
Method)
03-19 13:09:11.558: E/(8913): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:  
com.xyz.ab.ServiceWrapperContext cannot be cast to android.app.ContextImpl
03-19 13:09:11.558: E/(8913):  at      
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2501)
```

Code causing issue:

```
 protected void attachBaseContext( Context base ) {
 ServiceWrapperContext context = new ServiceWrapperContext( base );
 context.addCallback( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE,
            new TypefaceLayoutInflater.ServiceCallback( ) );
    super.attachBaseContext( context );
```

The ServiceWrapperContext  extends ContextWrapper.

When I comment the above method it works fine else gives the above exception.

Please help as my colleague had made these changes. I tried few things but its not working. Not able to understand the issue here.

Comment: What's the import for Context in your class, for instance : import com.aaaa.Context

Comment: @LaurentY its import android.content.Context;

Comment: Which line is the exception on?

Comment: Please post complete code of receiver and Logcat output

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure the following line causes the problem:

```
super.attachBaseContext( context );
```

You are passing an instance of ServiceWrapperContext class, instead of Context class. I am not sure about your class hierarchy, but maybe you should try calling:

```
super.attachBaseContext( base );
```

Answer (score 2):

`android.app.ContextImpl` is the base class that all other "base contexts" of activities must derive and is a subclass of the `android.content.Context` class. `ContextWrapper` is also a subclass of `android.content.Context`.

Obviously, you can't have [a class that subclasses 2 other classes in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594005/java-can-a-class-inherit-from-two-super-classes-at-the-same-time), but you have to provide a `ContextImpl` as the base class. (Based on [ContextImpl docs](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#ContextImpl), note that even though the method requires a `Context` the `Activity` or `BroadcastReciever` assumes it is a `ContextImpl`).

The reason why your colleague used `ContextWrapper` instead is because they wanted to add functionality to the base context without altering whatever functionality it already has. ContextWrapper delegate all its `Context` implementations by calling the implementation of its base context, but since the activity expects additional functionalities (in the form of `ContextImpl`) this will not work here. You can either create a `ContextImplWrapper` that does with `ContextImpl` objects what `ContextWrapper` does with `Context` objects, or implement what the `ServiceWrapperContext` does in some other way.